# What algorithms apart from FFT get a computational boost by leveraging complex numbers?

Tags: polynomials, fast-fourier-transform

If we think of the algorithmic problem of doing a convolution of two arrays, it turns out that converting them to the frequency domain first and then doing an element-wise product is equivalent. And this leads to an efficient algorithm where we invoke the FFT to go to the frequency domain efficiently (in $O(n \log(n))$ time).

Are there other examples of algorithmic problems where the framing of the problem doesn't involve complex numbers (and it wouldn't be out of place on leetcode or a coding interview) and yet to solve it in the most efficient manner, invoking complex numbers is required?

Comment: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/15057/complex-analysis-in-theoretical-computer-science